# JSessionID is overwritten when switching between HTTP and HTTPS. How to solve?

Tags: java, cookies, jboss, load-balancing, jsessionid

We have the following situation going on:

1. Go to **http**://website/ and click on a link to **http**://website/appX
   Check that the cookie shows JSessionID with secure = NO.
2. Open another browser window or tab and go to **https**://website/ and click on a link to **https**://website/appY.
   Check that the cookie shows JSessionID with secure = YES.
3. Try to interact with the window/tab created in step 1. I'm getting a session expired...

If we repeat the steps but use **https**://website/appX instead of **https**://website/appY in step2, then the JSessionID cookie remains with Secure=NO.

All cookies have JSessionId with jvmRoute appended in the end.

--

We are using:

Apache (2.2.3-43.el5_5.3) + mod_jk (w/ sticky sessions) and load balancer configured to several JBoss instances (v 4.3.0).

I have found only a link with the exact same issue (normally the other ones are using PHP):
http://threebit.net/mail-archive/tomcat-users/msg17687.html

Q: How can we prevent the JSessionId cookie from being rewritten ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connector configuration (for Tomcat's bundled version in JBoss) in deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml, there's an `emptySessionPath` attribute that controls whether the session cookie is set on the context path or not.

```
<Connector port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"    
     maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
     emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
     connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

If you set this to false, you'll have one cookie per application, which prevents the problem from happening.

Answer (score 2):

From a security point of view, it is the correct behavior, because a attacker could steal the session id/cooki used in https if the same session id/cooki is used in http too.

For more details see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545074/spring-security-remember-me-authentication-from-https-to-http-cookie-writing-fail/5548581#5548581).

So if you want to build a secure application (I excpect this, because you use https), then you must not change this!

Comment: Thanks for that. This was my belief as well... So how can SSL and non-SSL co-exist without the non-SSL session expire because of a new SSL session ?

Comment: @altosaxwannabe: Make the HTTP resources available for HTTPS too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. They are already available through both http:// and https://

Comment: @altosaxwannabe sorry I mashed your question with the one I was refering in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

SessionID/Cookie will not be preserved when making switch from HTTPS to HTTP or vice versa. You can pass these parameters in URL to pass the values.

Comment: Hi, they are being preserved if I access the same application. (i.e. I can use **http**://website/appX and **https**://website/appX interchangeably).