# Forbidden error when I access HTTP and HTTPS URLs

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https, liferay-6

I have a website (Liferay portal 6.1 and Tomcat 7.0) which is having HTTP and HTTPS URL like below.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/profile

I follow below steps and I am getting Forbidden error:

1. I fill some form details in 2nd URL.
2. Before submitting that form I open 1st URL in a new tab.
3. Then if I come back to 1st URL and do a submit then I found a forbidden error.

I checked JSESSIONID at both tabs, Ids are same. What may be the issue? Any idea guys?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeSummers yes, But I don't know which part of code I have to post here

Comment: @CrazyJavaLearner everything needed to reproduce the error.  Also information like what container or HTTP implementation you are using.

Comment: There are multiple look-alike questions here, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595916/jsessionid-is-overwritten-when-switching-between-http-and-https-how-to-solve, did you check them?

Comment: @user3707125 But in my case JSESSIONID is not override. It's same as previous.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that apparently these guys are trying to make something similar to your case, and thus you may be able to find out how to fix your issue. Maybe I am wrong, I didn't dig deeply.

Comment: @user3707125 Yes, they are similar for some extends. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not worth investing time in making http/https mixed mode work ([in my opinion](https://www.olafkock.de/ok/2014/12/30/http_and_https_mixed_mode_configuration.html)). Bite the bullet and just go https always. Even if you'd fix *this* issue now, chances are that you'll run into more issues later, eating up more of your time. And when you run into other issues, they're highly likely security sensitive.

Do yourself a favor - unconditionally redirect ALL http traffic to https. It's 2016, there's nothing unusual with this any more.

Edit after your comment: Do this *especially* if it's an old system (by the way, this was obvious when you mentioned Liferay 6.1. Assuming you're using CE, it's long out of updates): Configure the use of https anywhere you can easily get your hands on. Unconditionally add the HSTS header to take care of the rest. No need to touch any ancient logic. E.g. set

```
web.server.protocol=https
```

in your [portal-ext.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Web%20Server). Add the HSTS header to your Apache httpd unconditionally (assuming you have Apache httpd, otherwise use [this Liferay App](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/27551660) from yours truly).

Comment: can understand, but this is an old system. Where I have fix this issue for now.

Comment: For static page they are using http, which they dont want to change.

Comment: Are they also willing to pay the price? Check the link to my blog article - there is a significant price for making it work. That price is the probability of mistakes. And the mistakes might be security related. It's so much easier (and cheaper - not necessarily only in money) if you (they) go with https-only. IMHO "don't want" is not a strong enough reason to accept the price. If - *for some reason e.g. of compatibility* - they'd *must* still support http - that would be something different. You still haven't convinced me ;)