# Spring Security 3.1.0 - Cannot switch from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: java, https, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security, so I made a small webapp in order to try it and find a configuration that will be useful for the project I am working on.
I am forcing my login page to be accessed via HTTPS, and I need to switch back to HTTP after logging in. In other words:

- Login page: HTTPS only
- Other pages: HTTP only

I tried several ways but I cannot make it work as I said above.
I read the [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session) and I see that there is no "natural" way of doing what I want, but I have been asked to do so, hence I need a workaround which I cannot find by myself.

I am using Spring Security 3.1.0.
My web container is Tomcat 6.0.33.

This is my Spring Security configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/log*.htm" access="anonymous"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('admin')"
            requires-channel="http" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            requires-channel="http" access="hasRole('authenticated')" />

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.htm"
            default-target-url="/index.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error=true"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout.htm" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <sec:anonymous/>
        <sec:remember-me use-secure-cookie="true" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="johnny" password="johnny" authorities="authenticated, admin" />
                <sec:user name="charlie" password="charlie"
                    authorities="authenticated" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's considered ill-advised to do that; it permits the session cookie to be stolen, Firesheep-style.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not the correct solution, but I also think it depends on the type of application you are building and the server load you would admit. Unfortunately, in this case I have been asked to do so due to some (dark) reasons. Thank you for your comment anyway, we should not forget that this approach is quite vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found for this problem is disabling Spring Security's default session fixation protection. I had to add a "session-management" element to the XML configuration I first described.

```
<sec:http auto-config="true">

    <!-- ... -->

    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>

    <!-- ... -->
</sec:http>
```

In addition to this, the URL we have to provide as the "application URL" is not the login URL but the Home Page URL, e.g. NOT http://myapp/login.htm BUT http://myapp/index.htm. Doing so, if the user is logged in or has a remember-me cookie, they will be able to enter without problem and the browser keeps using HTTP protocol. If not, the user is redirected to the login page using HTTPS, and after a successful login the browser switches back to HTTP correctly. Please take this into account, because if you write (or click) the login URL directly, HTTPS will be maintained all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by adding a filter into the filter chain that changes your cookie

In your config file create the filter and add it into the filter chain as follows:

```
<bean name="httpsCookieFilter" class="bla.bla.bla.HttpsCookieFilter"/>

<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
...
    <security:custom-filter position="FIRST" ref="httpsCookieFilter" />
...
</security:http>
```

And your Filter code looks something like this

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Sessions created under HTTPS, for which the session cookie is marked as “secure”, cannot subsequently be used under 
 * HTTP. The browser will not send the cookie back to the server and any session state will be lost (including the
 * security context information)
 *
 * Tomcat tracks user sessions with the help of the JSESSIONID cookie. If you enter into HTTPS with Tomcat, the cookie
 * will come back with the secure property being set to true. Subsequently when the redirection to http occurs, the
 * browser will not transmit the JSESSIONID cookie and you'll get a new session.
 *
 * This filter overrides the default Tomcat JSESSIONID behaviour
 */
public class HttpsCookieFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        final HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);

        if (session != null) {
            final Cookie sessionCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.getId());
            sessionCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
            sessionCookie.setSecure(false);
            sessionCookie.setPath(httpRequest.getContextPath());
            httpResponse.addCookie(sessionCookie);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Anyway, for some reason this filter approach did not work for me. In the meantime I found another way to make it work, which I will explain in a separate answer. I think both approaches should be tried by any developer who might have the same problem.